# CiviContribute Dashboard Chart Layout does not display

Tags: contributions, dashboard, chart

CiviContribute dashboard does not show chart_layout.   Tested on Civi Demo as well as several installations.  is there a configuration requirement?

See image[image: ChartMissing]

Answer (score 3):

Problem is Flash being blocked.     Although it is globally enabled, for some reason it is being blocked.   Solved problem with this process to specifically trust site for Flash.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Many thanks, Dave. I just noticed that my CiviContribute charts were also not displaying. I only use Chrome and this saved me. This does beg the larger question. Why does CiviCRM use Flash for graphics? It will soon be obsolete and it would be good to remove this archaic dependency.